# How to resolve the console warning in virtual android simulator while running React-native application in it?

Tags: react-native, expo, simulator

I am trying to run android simulator using following command in my react-native project's terminal.

```
npm start
```

After some process I am entering 'a' to start android simulator.

Metro is started but there is warning on simulator's screen, after this warning android simulator stopped to Synchronize with my project. I mean after getting this warning if I am changing some code in my App.js file then it's not reflecting here in android simulator.

[This is the screenshot of warning screen which I got in my Android simulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLGFO.png)

**App.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello world!!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container:{
     paddingVertical:12,
     paddingHorizontal:16,
   }
});
```

**App.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "quizzer",
    "slug": "quizzer",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

If I am trying to run app in physical simulator via USB in **Expo Go** Android application then it's showing that ***Something went wrong. Network response timed out***. Expo Go's error log is saying that

```
Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:failed to connect /192.168.106.102 (port 19001) from /56.159.178.246(port 38648) after 10000ms

15:51:01 Fatal Error
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Stick to the steps:

1. On your phone, enable USB Tethering and USB Debugging Mode.
2. Use a USB cable to connect your phone to your PC.
3. Now just change the ip address (run `ipconfig` in cmd) from your backend code.

For me, the above solution worked.

Give it a shot. It'll work out.

Please let me know if any errors occur, and if the solution works, please leave a comment.